# Entering positional argument with argument key?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to enter a positional argument with it's key name. Here is my example.py file:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('receiver', help="Enter receiver email ID")                    
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now I want to enter the the argument as: `python3 example.py receiver <argument>`
I want to use 'receiver' key to enter corresponding argument.

Comment: You have to define two `positional` arguments or one with `nargs=2`.  Then interprete the 2 strings yourself,  Or just get the strings from `sys.argv` directly.  `argparse` is meant for controlled input, not a freeform 'key=value' kind of input.

Comment: Once you have two strings, such as `Namepace['arg1'='receiver', 'arg2'='foobar']`, you can do `setattr(arrs, args.arg1, args.arg2).

Comment: Thanks, using setattr(), It works but I was looking for something within the argparse library. Something like optional argument with 'allow_abbrev=False'. I am just confused, this feature is given to the optional argument but not for positional one. Is there any better library equivalent to argparse?

Comment: `opitionals` are identified by the flag string, and (can) take an argument. `positionals` are identified by position, and are themselves the argument.  You are trying to supply ttwo positionals.